# Authentication Required popup `/bin/sh`

Tags: authentication

My Ubuntu 18.04 opens the modal dialog

> Authentication Required

with the text
"Authentication is needed to run '/bin/sh' as super user

This happens just after booting - for no reason know to me!

[image]

Comment: Gnome, XFCE or KDE?

Comment: Is ubuntu budgie

Comment: I don't know where Budgie stores the programs that will run at startup.

I would look there first.

Comment: The fact that the dialog doesn't show the app/process that initiated the request [is a bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/2204#note_709361)

Comment: Got the same today on 20.04, but apparently just once

Comment: May indeed have been dropbox: I did an experiment to see how a root owned file would be handled. Even as I changed the ownership and deleted the file, I got the popup, however not on a subsequent boot.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have Dropbox installed?

> If Dropbox finds files in its folder that aren't owned by your user, it will try to run a script with super user privileges to change the ownership of those files to your user.
>
> If you click *Cancel*, Dropbox won't run the script but you'll continue to get the popup because it will continue to detect the problem.
>
> If you're able to confirm it is Dropbox causing the popup, then the solution is to enter your credentials and let it run the script.

More details [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1202984/18665).

I myself ran into this problem, but since I run Xfce the dialog has an expandable *Details* option that allowed me to figure out the source of the popup:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why doesn't this window give any indication which task wants to run /bin/sh as root? This is super dangerous and could easily be malware. Kinda like: just trust the unknown and enter the password so the trojan can encrypt all your files ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I also have the same issue

Since I did not want to just allow it - since I don't know what it is - I did this:

1. Check for programs that are starting after boot by opening "Startup Applications"

   [image]

   And verify that only desired applications do start.
2. If you have Dropbox (like pointet out by bmaupin) then search for files which you are not the owner of

   ```
   ls -Rl Dropbox/ |grep -vP 'YourUserName|total|Dropbox.*:|^$'

   this Searches for all files where the user is not YourUserName, omits Parent Directories of files and also omits empty lines
   ```
3. Change the ownership of files to your user (`$USER`) and group

   ```
   sudo chown YourUserName:YourGroupName /path/do/file
   ```

Comment: I would find those unreadable files [this way](https://askubuntu.com/a/1239278/349837)

Comment: A good solution but a better way to search would be "find Dropbox ! -user USERNAME" because it will show the full path to the file. Although not recommended because you don't know if a file needs to be owned by some other user (but shouldn't in the Dropbox folder) you could use "sudo find Dropbox ! -user USERNAME -exec chown USERNAME:USERNAME {} \;" to find and fix all the files.